# if condition is getting failed in ios9 due to boolean and interger arithmetic operation

Tags: objective-c, notifications, ios9

my if condition is failed in ios 9 , but it works fine in ios 8,

```
bool countOfBadges;
```

countOfBadges is `YES`,

```
 if (countOfBadges-1!=0) {
    // statements
    }
    else{
    //statements
    }
```

in ios 8 it is going inside the if condition , but in ios 9 it is going to else statement .

Comment: It's unlikely that the bug is in this code, you gave us too little. Btw. please format the code because right now it's unreadable.

Comment: And why do you subtract integer from bool value instead of checking something like this: `if (!countOfBadges)` or even `if (countOfBadges == false)`. And countOfBadges is a bad name for a bool.

Comment: Try untangling your data types.  `YES` should be used with `BOOL`, not `bool`.  Don't rely on the underlying representation...`bool` may be `int` or its own type depending on which language standard you're using.  It's quite possible for `true` to be any non-zero value, making arithmetic with `bool` just as risky as you have discovered.